# Hi, I am writing a program that picks the season and I can't seem to make the last part work " if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21)"

Tags: java, class, ide

I can't seem  to make the last part work 
This really annoying me please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mylab
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int month;
        int day;
        String season= "seasons";


        System.out.print("type a two digit month");
        System.out.print(" and day");
        month = in.nextInt();
        day = in.nextInt();


        String winter = " winter ";
        String summer = " summer";
        String spring = " spring";

        System.out.print(" Month="+ month +" Day= "+day);

        if (month <= 3)
        {
            System.out.println(" Winter");
        }
        else if (month <= 6)
        {
            System.out.println(" Spring ");
        }
        else if (month <= 9)
        {
            System.out.println(" Summer ");
        }
        else if (month <= 12)
        {
            System.out.println(" Fall");
        }

        // I am having trouble with this part
        // is there a simple solution ?      
        if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21)
        {
            if (season == winter)
                System.out.println(" Spring");
        }
        else if (season == spring)
        {
            System.out.println ("Summer");
        }
        else if (season == summer)
        {
            System.out.println (" Fall");
        }
        else if (season == winter)
        {
            System.out.println(" winter");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've given for "this part" doesn't exist in the rest of your code. Your question is very hard to understand at the moment...

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what's the expected behaviour and the problem you're facing.

Comment: I'm not sure what your approach is, but you may want to represent the season as an integer (0 to 3), compute that, and _then_ convert it to a string.

Comment: The assignment was IF month is 1,2, or 3, season = "Winter
Else if month is 4, 5, or 6, season = "Spring"
Else if month is 7,8, 9, season = "Summer"
Else if month is 10,11, or 12, season = "Fall"
If month is divisible by 3 and day >= 21
     If season is "Winter", season = "Spring"
     Else if season is "Spring", season = "Summer"
     Else if season is "Summer", season = "Fall"
     Else season = "Winter"

Comment: @user3251123 Looks like you forgot to include a `{` after the line `if (season == winter)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it. You had `}` in the wrong places.

Also, you should compare `Strings` with `.equals` instead of `==`, or you'll be comparing the reference.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int month;
    int day;
    String season= "seasons";


    System.out.print("type a two digit month");
    System.out.print(" and day");
    month = in.nextInt();
    day = in.nextInt();


    String winter = " winter ";
    String summer = " summer";
    String spring = " spring";
    String fall = " fall";

    System.out.print(" Month="+ month +" Day= "+day);

    if (month <= 3)
    {
        //System.out.println(" Winter");
        season = winter;
    }
    else if (month <= 6)
    {
        //System.out.println(" Spring ");
        season = spring;
    }
    else if (month <= 9)
    {
        //System.out.println(" Summer ");
        season = summer;
    }
    else if (month <= 12)
    {
        //System.out.println(" Fall");
        summer = fall;
    }


    if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21) {

        if ( season.equals(winter) )  
            season = spring;
             //System.out.println(" Spring");

        else if ( season.equals(spring) ) 
            season = summer;
            //System.out.println ( "Summer" );

        else if ( season.equals(summer) ) 
            season = fall;
            //System.out.println ( " Fall");

        else if ( season.equals(winter) ) 
            season = winter;
            //System.out.println( " winter");
    }   

    System.out.println(season);
}
```

Output example:

```
type a two digit month and day9 31
 Month=9 Day= 31 fall
```

Comment: it still doesn't work.

Comment: The pseudo tells me if "If month is divisible by 3 and day >= 21" it will  If season is "Winter", season = "Spring"
     Else if season is "Spring", season = "Summer"
     Else if season is "Summer", season = "Fall"
     Else season = "Winter"               so I  try  putting in month 9 and day 31 and it tells me the season is Summer , but it is supposed come up with Fall

Comment: I think you've just forgot to update the season in the first part of the program, so it isn't verified in the end. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Check my new edit. Mark answer as accepted if that solved your problem. Hope it helped ;)